# Exception in procedure

Tags: oracle

I have procedure like below, but when block is run it does not shows message for error if data is not found.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PROCEDURE DDPROJ_SP
  (P_IDPROJ IN DD_PROJECT.IDPROJ%TYPE,
   P_INFO OUT VARCHAR2,
   p_check OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
  CURSOR cur_ddproj IS
  SELECT *
  FROM   dd_project
  WHERE  idproj = p_idproj;
  lv_projinfo_txt VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  FOR rec_ddproj IN cur_ddproj LOOP
        lv_projinfo_txt := (rec_ddproj.idproj||', '||rec_ddproj.projname||
                           ', '||rec_ddproj.projstartdate||', '||rec_ddproj.                                 projenddate||
                           ', '||rec_ddproj.projfundgoal||', '||rec_ddproj.p                                rojcoord);
  END LOOP;
  P_INFO := LV_PROJINFO_TXT;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
   P_CHECK :='Please select another project';
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(P_CHECK);
END;
```

And block:

```
DECLARE
   LV_INFO_TXT VARCHAR2(100);
   LV_CHECK_TXT VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN
   DDPROJ_SP(00,lv_info_txt,lv_check_txt);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(LV_INFO_TXT);
END;
```

After RUNNING BLOCK IF id provided is correct I would receive requested information but if ID is not found exception will not show message on print.

Comment: if you are running from sqlplus, need to enable:  set serveroutput on

Comment: Thank you OldProgrammer, Serveroutput was on, I ll try down below, I believe that's where issue is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, as has been pointed out, your exception handler doesn't do anything really visible except call `dbms_output`, the results of which you'll only see if you `set serverout on` or otherwise access the results from `dbms_output`.

Secondly and more importantly, when you use a `FOR` loop to process the results of a cursor, the `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception will never be raised.

If you want to detect no rows found, you have a few options:

1. After the loop, check if the variable was set, e.g.:

   ```
   ...
   end loop;

   if lv_projinfo_txt is null then
     raise no_data_found;
   end if;
   ```
2. If you don't expect more than 1 record to be found by the query (which is suggested by your predicate on an "id"), you can avoid the `FOR` loop and use a simple `select into`:

   ```
   PROCEDURE DDPROJ_SP
     (P_IDPROJ IN DD_PROJECT.IDPROJ%TYPE,
      P_INFO OUT VARCHAR2,
      p_check OUT VARCHAR2)
   IS

     rec_ddproj dd_project%rowtype;

     lv_projinfo_txt VARCHAR2(100);
   BEGIN

     SELECT *
     into   rec_ddproj
     FROM   dd_project
     WHERE  idproj = p_idproj;

     lv_projinfo_txt := (rec_ddproj.idproj||',     '||rec_ddproj.projname||
                        ', '||rec_ddproj.projstartdate||', '||rec_ddproj.projenddate||
                        ', '||rec_ddproj.projfundgoal||', '||rec_ddproj.projcoord);

     P_INFO := LV_PROJINFO_TXT;
   EXCEPTION
     WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      P_CHECK :='Please select another project';
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(P_CHECK);
   END;
   ```

Notes:

- A `select into` may raise `NO_DATA_FOUND` or `TOO_MANY_ROWS`.
- Good practice is to never handle errors without re-raising the exception, unless your code *actually handles* the exception. In your case, your code merely sends a signal back to the calling process via the `p_check` parameter, which moves responsibility for handling the error to the caller. This might be ok in some circumstances but it assumes the caller actually heeds the signal. It would be better to raise an exception which forces the caller to handle it appropriately.
- Good practice is to alias all columns and parameters in a query; having a SQL predicate like `idproj = p_idproj` makes the assumption that the table will never have a column called `p_idproj` in the future. Instead, it's good practice to deliberately alias all columns and parameters, e.g.

  ```
  SELECT x.*
  into   rec_ddproj
  FROM   dd_project x
  WHERE  x.idproj = ddproj_sp.p_idproj;
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, it make sense now!